# Cannot make ARToolKit on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gstreamer, ubuntu-12.04, artoolkit

I'm running **Ubuntu 12.04** on an Asus eee PC and after following the **ARToolKit** tutorials, when I get to the `make` part after choosing **GStreamer** I get a lot of "undefined reference" errors in VideoGStreamer/video.c . Pastebin here:

http://pastebin.com/BHz60Wyb

I asked the same question at #gstreamer on freenode and they hint it could be a problem with ARToolKit. And then I saw this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=2260b48cec6cd38078e5f9f6d7beee47&p=12091315&postcount=3

Official ARToolKit support seems to be dead as for now, so that's why I'm asking this here.

Thank you for reading my sad story.

**UPDATE**: I found a patch made by Mr. Yoshinari Kameda that works with V4L2 + Ubuntu perfectly at http://www.kameda-lab.org/_local/imagelab.tsukuba.ac.jp/ubuntu1004+opencv21/ARToolKitk/index-e.html

Answer (score 0):

```
-Download "freeglut3-dev" form Ubuntu Software center
-Download "libxmu-dev" form Ubuntu Software center
-Download "libXi-dev" form Ubuntu Software center
-Download "libglew1.5-dev" form Ubuntu Software center
**I don't know if the next two downloads are necessary**
-Download "GStreamer plugins for mms, wavpack, quicktime,
musepack" form Ubuntu Software center
-Download "GStreamer plugins for aac, xvid, mpeg2, faad" form Ubuntu
Software center
-Dowload "libgstreamer0.10-dev" form Ubuntu Software center

-Download "ARToolKit-2.72.1.tgz"
-unzip "ARToolKit-2.72.1.tgz"
-Download the scrpit "installARToolKit.sh" from this website:
 github.com/enekochan/installation-scripts
-Run the script.
+Select option 6 "GStreamer Media Framework"
+Select n
+Select n
-Type the following commands:
+cd ARtoolkit/bin
+./simpleTest
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and let you know the results.